# AndroidMainfest - should an intent-filter have multiple actions?

Tags: android, android-manifest

My current intent-filter for my MainActivity looks like this

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Notice that there are 2 action nodes. Is this correct? Or should there only be one action node per intent-filter?

Also, what is the purpose of the DEFAULT category?

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Comment: It is the default entry point for your application

Comment: ok thanks for all the replies, so at least 1 action per intent-filter. I assume DEFAULT is optional

Comment: "I assume DEFAULT is optional" -- that would be an incorrect assumption. It depends on the `Intent` that will be used to access the component, and what the component is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this correct?

It can be, though in this case I suspect it is not what you want.

This `<intent-filter>` will match:

- an `Intent` with the `MAIN` action and the `LAUNCHER` category, or
- an `Intent` with the `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` and the `LAUNCHER` category

The former is common. However, I rather doubt that `USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` will be used with the `LAUNCHER` category. I am not even sure it is used with *activities*, as the documentation is a bit muddled on this point.

Answer (score 9):

A intent filter can have n number of actions based on your activity need. For instance if your application receives one or multiple images from a social sharing app then you would use

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
```

For reference look at the [Example Filters section of this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html).

Answer (score 3):

yes, from docs for `<action>` element:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

> Adds an action to an intent filter. An  element must
>   contain one or more  elements. If it doesn't contain any, no
>   Intent objects will get through the filter. See Intents and Intent
>   Filters for details on intent filters and the role of action
>   specifications within a filter.

Answer (score 1):

An intent filter can apply to many actions. But it means in the receiving code you will need to check which intent action was activated. For example:

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
```

Such as

```
boolean ndefAction = NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals (intent.getAction ());
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it and it won't work without adding DEFAULT inside category.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <!--This is required-->
</intent-filter>
```