# Process is not permitted to autostart boot complete broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following message from the logcat:

```
08-16 11:34:36.257: W/BroadcastQueue(1040):
 Unable to launch app com.abc.xyz/10192 for broadcast Intent
 { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }: process is not permitted to autostart
```

My manifest.xml looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> 
<receiver android:name="com.abc.xyz.BootComplete" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have tried so many methods but its not working.I know there is some other problem.Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to add permission, in the `manifest.xml`

Comment: RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED add this permission

Comment: are you installing the app in internal or external storage

Comment: @ArlindI have already added that permission.You can see above on the xml file code.

Comment: where is the app being installed, in the devices internal or external storage?

Comment: @Arlind I have installed on internal storage.I do not have sd card now.

Comment: what type of device are you using?

Comment: I am using phone, tried on huawei and xiaomi phones,but it is not working.But it is working on samsung devices.

Comment: Has the app been "disabled" in app manager settings ?

Comment: there is a bug on xiaomi and huawei devices, I saw the same problem on other posts, didnt find a solution to it

Comment: there might be a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627856/reboot-receiver-is-not-working-in-xiaomi-phones

Comment: That's a dead end then.But I can see other apps which are being run on boot complete on the phone.Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

On Xiamoi your application will be blocked from autostart on reboot by default (unlike it Facebook or Whatsapp, that allowed to run). 
As a user you can change this limitation in built in Security application, in Manage apps ->  -> Autostart. As a developer, I didn't found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

On Xiaomi devices, you can open the screen for users to enable autostart permission with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm aware this is an old question but it might be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

I developed a library that helps a user add your app to autostart, you can check it out here.

[AutoStarter](https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter)