# Boot BroadcastReceiver does not work on Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, android-broadcastreceiver, android-reboot

I have a following `BroadcastReceiver` which should run after boot completion. I have tested it on my **Xiaomi device (Redmi 1s)**, it's not running, while on other devices like **Samsung** it's running as expected.

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "I am Running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have set permission in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

And following is my broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.DeviceBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I have problem with android 8 xamoi phones with RECEIVE_SMS when app is in background and Receiver is triggred but message is empty. Do have any idea about this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I searched around the web and found a solution, I've decided to answer my own question. Follow the same code given in the question.

In **Xiaomi devices**, you just have to add your app to **Autostart** list, to do so, follow these simple steps given below:

1. Open **Security** app on your phone.
2. Tap on **Permissions**, it'll show you two options: Autostart and
   Permissions
3. Tap on **Autostart**, it'll show you list of apps with on or off toggle
       buttons.
4. Turn on toggle of your app, you're done!

Now, reboot your phone, you'll see a Toast message **I am Running**

Comment: You have helped me a lot! I did not know about this :)

Comment: @Dimitar : oh! I'm glad that it helped you.

Comment: I cant see Autostart option in Xiaomi hm note1 LTE

Comment: Man you saved my life... I guess I would have never found this solution...

Comment: @Salivan I am glad :)

Comment: But how to do this automatically ? User isn't going to do this.

Comment: @bdevloper I also don't know, it's Xiaomi's policy, permission or we can say a security feature for apps.

Comment: I have problem with android 8 xamoi phones with RECEIVE_SMS when app is in background and Receiver is triggred but message is empty. Do have any idea about this?