# What is the use of category DEFAULT with broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, categories, android-broadcast

What is the use of the category "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" with respect to broadcast receiver?

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.InputReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.amazon.intent.action.CUSTOM_A" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/category-element) says that to match any implicit intents add the category default.

> Note: In order to receive implicit intents, you must include the
>   CATEGORY_DEFAULT category in the intent filter. The methods
>   startActivity() and startActivityForResult() treat all intents as if
>   they declared the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category. If you do not declare it
>   in your intent filter, no implicit intents will resolve to your
>   activity.

After Android-O, I will not be able to send implicit broadcasts. Does that mean "CATEGORY_DEFAULT" will not be useful with broadcasts?

I'm quite confused with the use of CATEGORY_DEFAULT with broadcast and activity. Can someone clarify me please? What is the right scenario to use CATEGORY_DEFAULT and what would happen if I didn't add it?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the right scenario to use CATEGORY_DEFAULT

When you call `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, if the `Intent` has no categories in it, the framework will *add* `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` to the `Intent`, before trying to identify the component that should respond to that `Intent`. This is why an `<intent-filter>` for an `<activity>` usually has a `<category>` element, either for `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` or for some other category.

When you call `startService()`, `bindService()`, or `sendBroadcast()`, if the `Intent` has no categories in it, the framework leaves the `Intent` alone. This is why an `<intent-filter>` for a `<service>` or `<receiver>` often lacks a `<category>` element, as no category is required.

> and what would happen if I didn't add it?

If an `Intent` contains a category, and your `<intent-filter>` does not contain the category, your `<intent-filter>` will not match the `Intent`. This is why we normally need a `<category>` with `<activity>`, since the `Intent` probably has a category on it.

In the case of `com.amazon.intent.action.CUSTOM_A` from your `<receiver>` in your code snippet, apparently Amazon elected to add `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` to their broadcast `Intent` manually. That's odd but it is allowed by the SDK.

Comment: so, do I need add a DEFAULT category for a receiver? For a BOOT_COMPLETE receiver, for example? It's just part about receivers sounds ambiguous

Comment: @JohnnyFive: "do I need add a DEFAULT category for a receiver?" -- generally, no, but it depends on how the `Intent` is constructed that is used for the broadcast. "For a BOOT_COMPLETE receiver, for example?" -- generally, you do not need a `<category>` for that. I cannot rule out some device manufacturer screwing something up, though.

Comment: "I cannot rule out some device manufacturer screwing something up, though." That is the 2nd time I encounter this assumption. First was here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836141/6325722 Is there any logic behind this assumption or it's just an intuition?

Comment: @JohnnyFive: "Is there any logic behind this assumption" -- device manufacturers tweak Android all the time, in ways that sometimes introduce incompatibilities.